# .net core mvc 5.0 not able to publish & deploy to IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, publish

I am not able to publish & deploy .net core mvc 5.0  to IIS.
I have published my web site but css and other files looks like not published

Working fine on debug mode, but not working on iis :(

I have added **app.UseStaticFiles();** on Configure, I and tried to give access related publish folder, but still not working

[image]

publish output
[image]

Comment: _".net core mvc 5.0"_ Do you mean ASP.NET Core 5 MVC?

Comment: Yes I mean 5 MVC

Comment: _"but css and other files looks like not published"_ Assuming you're using Visual Studio, can you double check what Build Action and Copy to Output  are set to for some of these missing files?

Comment: it looks succeeded, and added output as image

Comment: .NET 5 has no problems with IIS but it *did* reach End Of Life [3 years ago](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core). The oldest long-term support version is .NET 6, supported until November 2024. The current LTS version is .NET 8, supported until November 2026

Comment: What are you trying to do? Where are you publishing> The images you posted show warnings complaining that .NET Framework and .NET Core assemblies are mixed up. The specific warning is about an old .NET Framework version of the AWS SDK. I can't copy the actual warning from the image, which is why you *shouldn't* post images. Images can't be copied or googled. AWS doesn't support EOL runtime versions, including .NET 5

Comment: Is this a project you attempted to migrate from ASP.NET MVC 5 (which uses .NET Framework) to ASP.NET Core 5 (using on .NET the "new" name for .NET Core)?